# Reading CSV into a Spark Dataframe with timestamp and date types

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

It's CDH with Spark **1.6**.

I am trying to import this Hypothetical CSV into a apache Spark DataFrame:

```
$ hadoop fs -cat test.csv
a,b,c,2016-09-09,a,2016-11-11 09:09:09.0,a
a,b,c,2016-09-10,a,2016-11-11 09:09:10.0,a
```

I use **databricks-csv** jar.

```
val textData = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("nullValue", "null")
    .load("test.csv")
```

I use inferSchema to make the schema for the resulting DataFrame. printSchema() function gives me the following output for the code above:

```
scala> textData.printSchema()
root
 |-- C0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C5: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- C6: string (nullable = true)

scala> textData.show()
+---+---+---+----------+---+--------------------+---+
| C0| C1| C2|        C3| C4|                  C5| C6|
+---+---+---+----------+---+--------------------+---+
|  a|  b|  c|2016-09-09|  a|2016-11-11 09:09:...|  a|
|  a|  b|  c|2016-09-10|  a|2016-11-11 09:09:...|  a|
+---+---+---+----------+---+--------------------+---+
```

The C3 column has **String** type. I want C3 to have **date** type. To get it to date type I tried the following code.

```
val textData = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("nullValue", "null")
    .load("test.csv")

scala> textData.printSchema
root
 |-- C0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C3: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- C4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C5: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- C6: string (nullable = true)

scala> textData.show()
+---+---+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+
| C0| C1| C2|                  C3| C4|                  C5| C6|
+---+---+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+
|  a|  b|  c|2016-09-09 00:00:...|  a|2016-11-11 00:00:...|  a|
|  a|  b|  c|2016-09-10 00:00:...|  a|2016-11-11 00:00:...|  a|
+---+---+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+
```

The only difference between this code and the first block is the **dateFormat** option line (I use **"yyyy-MM-dd"** instead of **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"**).Now I get both C3 and C5 as **timestamps**(C3 is still not date). But for C5, the HH::mm:ss part is ignored and shows up as zeroes in the data.

Ideally I want C3 to be of type date, C5 to be of type timestamp and its HH:mm:ss part to be not ignored. My solution right now looks like this. I make the csv by pulling data in parallel from my DB. I make sure that I pull all dates as timestamps (Not ideal). So, the test csv looks like this now:

```
$ hadoop fs -cat new-test.csv
a,b,c,2016-09-09 00:00:00,a,2016-11-11 09:09:09.0,a
a,b,c,2016-09-10 00:00:00,a,2016-11-11 09:09:10.0,a
```

This is my final working code:

```
val textData = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    .schema(finalSchema)
    .option("nullValue", "null")
    .load("new-test.csv")
```

Here, I use the complete timestamp format (**"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"**) in dateFormat. I manually create the finalSchema instance where c3 is date and C5 is Timestamp type(Spark sql types). I apply these schema use the schema() function. The output looks like follows:

```
scala> finalSchema
res4: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(C0,StringType,true), StructField(C1,StringType,true), StructField(C2,StringType,true), StructField(C3,DateType,true), StructField(C4,StringType,true), StructField(C5,TimestampType,true), StructField(C6,StringType,true))

scala> textData.printSchema()
root
 |-- C0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C3: date (nullable = true)
 |-- C4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C5: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- C6: string (nullable = true)


scala> textData.show()
+---+---+---+----------+---+--------------------+---+
| C0| C1| C2|        C3| C4|                  C5| C6|
+---+---+---+----------+---+--------------------+---+
|  a|  b|  c|2016-09-09|  a|2016-11-11 09:09:...|  a|
|  a|  b|  c|2016-09-10|  a|2016-11-11 09:09:...|  a|
+---+---+---+----------+---+--------------------+---+
```

**Is there an easier or out of the box way to parse out a csv file (that has both date and timestamp type into a spark dataframe?**

Relevant Links:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#manually-specifying-options
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Answer (score 5):

With a infer option for non-trivial cases it will probably not return the expected result. As you can see in [InferSchema.scala](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/InferSchema.scala#L148):

```
if (field == null || field.isEmpty || field == nullValue) {
  typeSoFar
} else {
  typeSoFar match {
    case NullType => tryParseInteger(field)
    case IntegerType => tryParseInteger(field)
    case LongType => tryParseLong(field)
    case DoubleType => tryParseDouble(field)
    case TimestampType => tryParseTimestamp(field)
    case BooleanType => tryParseBoolean(field)
    case StringType => StringType
    case other: DataType =>
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException(s"Unexpected data type $other")
```

It will only try to match each column with a timestamp type, not a date type, so the "out of the box solution" for this case is not possible. But with my experience the "easier" solution, is directly define the schema with the [needed type](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/package-frame.html), it will avoid the infer option set a type that only matches for the RDD evaluated not the entire data. Your final schema is an efficient solution.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really elegant but you can convert from timestamp to date like this (check last line):

```scala
val textData = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("nullValue", "null")
    .load("test.csv")
    .withColumn("C4", expr("""to_date(C4)"""))
```